# Tutorial or sample code for parsing xml file using libxml2 in IPhone Application

Tags: iphone

I just want a tutorial demonstrating the parsing of XML File using libXml2 in Iphone . I found tutorials on TouchXMLand other but not the same for Libxml2
Please help if u can.

Answer (score 4):

Apple has an example iPhone project that parses some simple XML using both NSXMLParser and libxml2 SAX2.  You can find the project here:

> http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html

Although this isn't exactly a tutorial, it is working code.  It runs in the simulator out of the box.  Because it accomplishes the same task twice, you should be able to compare the libxml2 code to the NSXMLParser code to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Not even [these](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#Parsing)?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend TBXML. I use it everytime I need to parse a XML File. It's really easy to use. ;-)
See here: [TBXML Homepage](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html)

Comment: I actually need to Parse the File with libxml2 as it is required in my project .Also i read that the Parsing with libxml2 is  faster so I want to Parse with it only.
But Thanks anyways for your response and help.

Comment: TBXML is faster but only allows reading xml whereas libxml2 allows both read and write, you can check details here http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Answer (score 0):

A good sample is: 
http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/libxml2_push_parsing